# How to test App Actions using Google Assistant?

Tags: android, app-actions

According to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/overview) App actions feature is currently in developer preview mode.

It's not really clear for me if the App Actions can be tested using the Google Assistant from the Android device or only by using the App Actions test tool.

Does anybody know if it is possible to test the App Actions using the Google Assistant?

When the App Actions will be available in production ?

Answer (score 0):

Most BIIs are testable from App Action Test Tool(AATT) and Assistant. There are a few exceptions in which BIIs can only be tested on App Actions Test Tool or Assistant. You can check the BII reference docs to find out which BIIs are supported in your [locale](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents). In either case, you need to create a preview through AATT first.

App Actions can be submitted to production by submitting your App through the [Deployment request form](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/overview). Will keep you posted if this process changes through App Actions docs.